# Использование EntityManager в сервлетах - ошибка

Tags: java, servlet, tomcat

В тестовом примере пытаюсь использовать EntityManager для записи в БД простого entity, вылетает ошибка. Понимаю, что вся логика должна быть в бизнес-слое, но на данном этапе просто обучаюсь. Подскажите, где собака зарыта почему вылетает ошибка.
Использую tomcat EE, ORM - hibernate, ide: Idea

persistence.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="myPerName777" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>ee.Student</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/jpa1" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

beans.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
        bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ee7</groupId>
    <artifactId>ee7</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

entity Student - которого пытаемся сохранить в БД

```java
package ee;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
@RequestScoped
public class Student {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    int id;
    String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

И непосредственно сервлет, где пытаюсь сохранить entity в БД

```java
package ee;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

@WebServlet("/hello")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {


    EntityManagerFactory myFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myPerName777");
    EntityManager entityManager = myFactory.createEntityManager();


    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setName("John");

        EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        entityManager.persist(student);
        transaction.commit();
        entityManager.close();
        myFactory.close();

        System.out.println(student.getId());

        resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
        PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();
        pw.println("<H1>Hello!</H1>");
    }
}
```

После добавления строк в сервлет

```java
EntityManagerFactory myFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myPerName777");
EntityManager entityManager = myFactory.createEntityManager();
```

сервлет перестает открывать страничку с hello, а показывает 404. Также ничего не записывается в БД, хотя все настройки верные, если просто из main-класса тоже самое проводить, то нормально попадает в БД и нормально отрабатывают все настройки persistence.xml и beans.xml

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть дело?
Как использовать EntityManager в сервлете без ejb, а напрямую сразу получая объект из фабрики и т.п.?

Comment: Если вы получаете 404, то скорее всего вы не верно указали url.

Comment: Дело в том, что когда добавляю  при дебаге появляется ошибка, не совсем понятно, что с этим делать

Comment: <openjpa-3.1.0-rafcec21a1d489dff682a3ce7986fac6a1c80e8e0 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: The persistence provider is attempting to use properties in the persistence.xml file to resolve the data source. A Java Database Connectivity (JDBC) driver or data source class name must be specified in the openjpa.ConnectionDriverName or javax.persistence.jdbc.driver property. The following properties are available in the configuration: "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl@393fa2d".

Comment: Попробуй без `javax.persistence.schema-generation...`

Comment: Нет, все тоже самое)

Comment: добавьте стектрейс

Comment: Та же самая ошибка, при чем с SessionFactory и hibernate.cfg.xml все работает в сервлетах, а с EntityManager и persistence.xml ошибка, мне кажется копать надо в этом направлении https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40818396/unable-to-build-hibernate-sessionfactory-exception-from-now и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45538143/problems-with-cdi-in-setup-for-functional-testing-with-tomee-or-openejb-jetty , но у меня пока не получилось решить. Если вы нашли решение отпишитесь пожалуйста, уж очень интересно в чем проблема.

Comment: Получилось, зависимость ненужная была, а так
Вот решение https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40818396/unable-to-build-hibernate-sessionfactory-exception-from-nowhere